# Routing audio input to receive from TOP microphone on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, avfoundation

I am writing a little app to record multiple tracks and play them back over one another.
I am using the PlaybackAndRecord mode and i am routing my output to the main speakers.
Problem is that the bottom microphone is still being used for input as well so now I when I record I get the output from the other tracks really loud on the new track.
Here is what I have so far:

```
audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];    
OSStatus propertySetError = 0;
UInt32 allowMixing = true;
propertySetError = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);

UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);

[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Comment: What do you mean the "Top" microphone?

Comment: There is a microphone on the bottom of the iPhone, embedded with the speakers. There is also a microphone on the top of the iPhone, its a little whole next to the headphone jack.  Its used for noise cancelation, and also when using speaker phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AVAudioSession to get available inputs.  On my iPhone 5 it looks like this.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].availableInputs);

  "<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x14554400, type = MicrophoneBuiltIn; name = iPhone Microphone; UID = Built-In Microphone; selectedDataSource = Back>"
```

Then use one of these inputs to get availableDataSources, like this.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].availableInputs[0].dataSources);

  "<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription: 0x145afb00, ID = 1835216945; name = Bottom>",
  "<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription: 0x145b1870, ID = 1835216946; name = Front>",
  "<AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription: 0x145b3650, ID = 1835216947; name = Back>"
```

We can see that there are actually THREE microphones on this iPhone: top front, top back, and bottom.  Now you can set your preferred data source.

```
AVAudioSessionPortDescription *port = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].availableInputs[0];
for (AVAudioSessionDataSourceDescription *source in port.dataSources) {
    if ([source.dataSourceName isEqualToString:@"Back"]) {
        [port setPreferredDataSource:source error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that the above solution will _only_ work of the phone's locale is EN (English) - since dataSourceName is localized. Hence, the comparison will fail for all possible values. On iOS7 you should use the orientation property (e.g. AVAudioSessionOrientationBack). For older iOS version you better off checking the system-id value.