# How to detect only/specifically human voice?

Tags: ios, cordova, microphone, voice, voice-recognition

I am developing an application where I shall be plotting a realtime pitch-frequency graph based on the sound produced by the speaker.

Example: User says "hmmmmmmmmmmmmmm..." and a graph is being plotted simultaneously showing the frequency reached by the user at every 1/10th of a second.

Now, I have developed everything from top to bottom but the only problem which remains is that the background noise is also being captured while a user speaks or says something. Even if the user says something keeping the phone close to his lips, noise is still being captured and plotted.

I want to remove that noise.

I have tried going about Shout ToolKit and Shpinx but nothing is being that effective as it is slowing the plotting of graph.

I am making this app using phonegap.

Are there any better noise cancellation apis available [pref: open source]

Comment: Apple has a built in noise canceling system. (at least on iPhone) I don't know code to implement it but I know that's why they have two microphones on the iPhone, one near where your voice will be coming in if you are holding the phone like it's a phone (the microphone on the bottom of the device) and one near the top of the headphone jack (a little tiny hole)... the top hole listens simultaneously with the bottom hole and the only sound that is accepted is the sounds that is greatly louder on the bottom than the top... everything else is just white noise. 0:)

Comment: All that said, yes it is indeed possible (at least on iPhones) but, programmatically speaking, I don't know how... /:

Comment: The only two related articles I could find on the topic both had no answers.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273424/routing-audio-input-to-receive-from-top-microphone-on-iphone
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334755/using-only-the-top-mic-in-an-iphone